# How to see injected scripts in Chrome Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am injecting a partial into a page using $().html(content).  Part of the partial is JavaScript code in an inline script block I need to inspect.  When I look in the Sources tab in the Chrome Developer Tools it doesn't show the injected content.  All it shows is the original source.

Is there a way to gain access to the JavaScript?

#### Update

I am using Google Chrome 21.0.1180.77 but I also have Google Chrome Canary installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Sources tab (Elements, Resources, Network, Scripts, Timeline, Profiles, Audits, Console).

<s>The Elements tab always reflects the current state of the DOM, so it will show any injected scripts.</s>  EDIT: This appears to be wrong.

There's a Chrome issue about this:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=95352

You can add a [specially formed comment](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/08/11/give-your-eval-a-name-with-sourceurl/) to the injected JavaScript code, and it will then show up in the Scripts tab (but it still doesn't show up in the Elements tab, for whatever reason):

```
//@ sourceUrl=whatever.js
```

Comment: My elements tab shows the changes but not the new script tag.  And yeah I seem to recall my Sources tab use to be called Scripts.

Comment: You're right.  Updated my answer with a method that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**How to see injected snippets:**

In order for injected code to be visible, you will need to add a **sourceURL** comment to the top of the evaluated script, like one of the following:

```
//# sourceURL=//domain/file.js
//# sourceURL=http://domain/file.js
//# sourceURL=https://domain/file.js
//# sourceURL=//domain/file
```

Note, that without the `//` hinting at the protocol and some **domain** immediately following, then the injected snippet will not show up under sources by default.

**How to see injected snippets without a protocol and domain:**

Continuing, with just a file name, like so:

```
//# sourceURL=file.js
```

You will have to change the source settings by unchecking **Group by folder**. See image.

[image]